How to properly execute a runtime upgrade in a Relay Chain
I'm trying to make a runtime upgrade in a local Relay Chain, but the chain stalls and stop producing blocks after the migrations.
I'm using the polkadot-v1.5.0 as base, and trying to upgrade to the latest release. But even trying with a minor upgrade v1.5.0 -> 1.6.0 results in the same issue.
The process is the standard I believe, execute a System.SetCode using sudo.
Is there any kind of specifics when upgrading a relay chain that I'm missing?
